# Editing column with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Theres a table on the website with a header and 3 sub headers. Basically all the 3 column are texts with one having number followed by a text like "25,000 Credited". The table has 5 rows. It shows last 5 activity in the table. I need to add colors to the column that has values like "25,000 Credited" providing a condition there. If the values are less than 25,000 it should be green and if the values are more than 25,000 i should get green or whatever color. How am I suppose to do that when I can only edit rows using greasemonkey js.
Here is the table

Recent Activity

Time            Name      Amount

1 hour ago      John     24,045 Credited
3 hours ago     Andrews  36,181 Credited
11 hours ago    Russell  74,121 Credited
11 hours ago    Davids   52,964 Credited
17 hours ago    Helen    92,869 Credited

Comment: You have full access to the DOM from a greasemonkey user script. What is the specific problem? If you are already able to edit the table why can't you check cells and change color?

Comment: I know how to add rows to a static table. i simply dont know how to edit cells in a dynamic table.

Comment: Provide code currently being used to access the table

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4gk2ZZvy

Comment: var table = getTableByHeader("<th colspan=\"2\"align=\"center\">Recent Activity</th>");
   var row = document.createElement("tr");

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer on my own

```
var recent = GetTable("Recent Activity");

          for(var i = 2; i < recent.rows.length; i++) {
                if(recent.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML.match("No credits reported")) { break; }
                var credits = GetTextIn(recent.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML, "", " ").replace(/,/g, "");
                var min = 25000;

            var color = 'green';

            if(credits <  min) {
                color = 'yellow';
            }

            recent.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<div style="color: ' + color + '">' + recent.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML + '</div>';
          }
```